# I am unable to render the image using multer

Tags: node.js, multer

```
    if(req.user.id == req.params.id){
        try{
            let user = await User.findById(req.params.id)
            User.uploadedAvatar(req, res, function(err){
                if(err){
                    console.log("Error")
                }
                user.name = req.body.name;
                user.email = req.body.email;

                if(req.field){
                    user.avatar = User.avatarPath + "/"  + req.file.filename
                    req.flash("success", "Profile picture updated")
                }
                user.save();
                return res.redirect("back")
            })
        }catch{
            req.flash("error", "Error in uploading")
        return res.redirect("back")
        }
    }else{
        req.flash("error", "Unauthorized")
        return res.status(401).send("Unauthorized")
    }
}

---------------------------
```

" alt="" width="100">

<% if(user.id == profileUser.id){ %>
" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
" required >
" required>



<%}else{%>

Name: <%= profileUser.name %>

Email: <%= profileUser.email %>

<%}%>

```
-------------------------
```

app.use("/uplaods" ,express.static(__dirname + "/uploads"))

```
I am trying to upload the images, but there is some error in the function.
```